# chrome on android doesn't kill my session

Tags: android, google-chrome, php

How can i disable chrome's cache. I don't use caching, so i just register a session variable but it remember session variable on every opening.

This code works but, when i close and open chrome, it doesn't work

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION["mobile_redirect"]))
{
   $_SESSION['mobile_redirect']=1;
   header("Location:http://".$this->otherSiteData['servername']);
   exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide more info please? What are your cache headers? When you "close and open" Chrome, what are you doing (are you sure it's not just going into the background)?

Comment: I close the section, and open new section. And i have tried to exit after i open app :s It remember my session